# Cannot operate Amazon videos anymore

Tags: flash

I purchased a system 76 laptop, stock with Ubuntu 13.10 (BEAUTIFUL machine) but I can no longer operate Amazon videos, and nothing I try seems to fix it!

Since I've gone through all the threads to try to get hal, install .debs, etc.

I just get one dead end after another, and an older version of adobe flash player won't seem to install.

Comment: Amazon Videos not working has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It is a problem with Amazon's site now being incompatible with the version of Flash available for Linux.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why this question was downvoted, seems like an honest question form a noob that actually tried to do some research.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon video requires that you use a determined version of Flash, but Adobe don't offer support anymore for Linux. The only solution is using Google Chrome's Pepperflash implementation.

Or, you could wait until Firefox releases their flash implementation.